# Likelihood Ratio Test (LRT) for function of parameter

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

Let $X_1,...,X_n \in Poisson(\lambda)$. We want to test the following hypothesis:

$H_0: \theta = \theta_0, \ vs \ H_1: \theta \ne \theta_0$

Where $\theta = log(\lambda)$. From the invariance property of MLEs we know that if $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$ for $\theta$ then $g(\hat{\theta}_{MLE})$ holds for $g(\theta)$. So $\hat{\theta}_{MLE} = log(\hat{\lambda}_{MLE})$. But here comes the problem, the Poisson distribution does not include the parameter $log(\lambda)$, so how can I then specify the LRT? Should I use the logged distribution in the LRT and substitute $log(\lambda)$ with $log(\hat{\lambda}_{MLE})$ and $log(\lambda_{0})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing for $\theta = \theta_0$ or testing for $\lambda = \lambda_0$ is equivalent since $\log$ is a bijective map. So the p-value obtained by performing a standard likelihood ratio test (with $\lambda_{MLE}$) is also a p-value for the test about $\theta$.

Comment: I’ll clarify that $log$ is bijective on the acceptable $\lambda$ values for $Poisson(\lambda)$, not bijective on the whole real line, but we only need the former.